How to allow specific Content types in Mod Security?
I am using:

Ubuntu 24.04
Plesk Obsidian 18.0.62
Apache/2.4.59
ModSecurity
Fail2ban
Free ModSecurity Rules from Comodo

I want to add a ModSecurity rule to accept text/x-gwt-rpc content type.
Adding the line "text/x-gwt-rpc" to the file userdata_wl_content_type will not work as this is a periodically overwritten file.

First of all: what's you aim to enable/add a new content type?
The request's content type determines the used body processor inside of the WAF engine (mod_security2/libmodsecurity3). There are 4 different body processors:

www-urlencoded (default)
multipart
JSON
XML

I don't know anything about the mentioned rule set (Comodo Free Rules), if there is any restriction regarding the CT, you should change/extend it.
But ModSecurity won't provide any solution to real processing of the payload.

Adding the line "text/x-gwt-rpc" to the file userdata_wl_content_type will not work as this is a periodically overwritten file.

May be you can take a look at the msc_pyparser, this can help you to maintain the modifications after every rule set update. A brief summary: you can parse the rule set into a structure (YAML/JSON) which appears as a Python dictionary, then you can apply your modification(s) and write back the rule set in SecLang format.
It's totally context independent: I mean if you want to change a specific rule, you can do that, it does not matter in which file and which line is it. Parser will solve the issue.

Thank you very much for your answer. When my web app connects to my GWT servlet, the 210710 modSecurity rule fires a warning. After 5 warnings, the client address is banned during 600s. modsec_audit.log reports that I have to add content type: text/x-gwt-rpc in file userdata_wl_content_type. This works during 24H. But this file is dayly overwritten. There should be a custom content_type file that prevails over the rule set update but I cannot find it. Do I actually have to install msc_pyparser only for adding a content type...

You wrote that if you modified the mentioned file it works during 24 hours. I guess some job replaces the rules (update?). You should modify that workflow: download the updates release, parse it, add your modifications, write back the rules. You can do this with msc_pyparser.
